# What's the best way for displaying text on a Three.js geometry?

Tags: three.js

What's the prescribed way for displaying text on a geometry? For example, I have many cubes in a scene that will have a number on each side of the cube. I thought about using textures or sprites, but curious what would be most optimal. An important note is that many of these geometries will be dynamically loaded and removed -- I mention this, because I'd hate to create a texture for each variation of the possible text outputs--e.g. 'a1', 'a2', ..., 'b1', 'b2'--and instead, dynamically set the content.

Comment: create a texture with the whole font and create a rectangle geometry for every letter you want to print, map uvs for it correctly, you might want to create mipmap for the texture manually to ensure high quality of the letters

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... do you have some examples by chance? Are you saying that I create a texture for say... 0-9 and somehow map those (multiple textures) to the numbers I do need... since I can do 12 using a combination of 1 and 2? and not sure about mipmaps... thank you!

Comment: take a look at this [font generator](http://www.codehead.co.uk/cbfg/) and it should be obvious, the mipmap part is how to refine the texture for when the text is on some distant objects(default mimap generation blurs the text edges)

Comment: use canvas https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html